# How to convert a pdf file where every page contains 2 pages, to 1 page pdf?

Tags: pdf

I know the title is not very clear, but I just don't know what exactly to ask.
I have a pdf book, it's landscape oriented so every pdf's file page contains 2 pages of the book (if I print A4 page I get 2 A5 pages).

I want to convert that pdf so every pdf's page will contain just 1 book's page - maybe "cut" every pdf's page to 2 and save separately.

are there any Ideas how can I perform it ?

Comment: What have you already tried, and is this question specifically related to macOS based software? At the moment your question is very platform-generic, e.g. could easily as just apply to Windows. You can update your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a python script to 'de-booklet' a PDF. Sadly, Apple have now removed python from macOS (since Monterey 12.3), which now makes handing people useful scripts on macOS much more difficult.

Prior to Monterey 12.3, you could just run this script in the Terminal, with the filepath of your PDF as an argument:

https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/legacy%20(python%202)/Automator_Scripts/DeBooklet.py

You could also put it in an Automator or Shortcuts.app workflow, using the 'Run Shell Script' action.

But now you'll have to install python3 and the pyobjc library, and use a newer python3 script:

https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Python3/DeBooklet.py

I recommend installing python3 directly from python.org:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Once you've done that, in the Terminal, type `pip3 install pyobjc` and press Return.

If you want to run it as a Quick Action in the Finder, or from the Services menu, then see the options selected in this image from Shortcuts.app.

[image]